# GWT: creating associated jsarray

Tags: arrays, gwt

I want to create a js array of type

```
Name(
{title : "Mr.",firstname : "Bill",lastname : "Gates"},
{title : "Mr.",firstname : "Bill",lastname : "Gates"},
{title : "Mr.",firstname : "Bill",lastname : "Gates"}
)
```

So basically i want to create associated array.
All the examples are like converting javascript array to java but in my case i want the other way round. I will be filling this array from java.

`JSArray` and `JsMixedArray` seems to be doing this but i could figure out how to add to them.

Comment: Why do you need this? You can use java map

Comment: I had to pass it to a external js library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be to use a [JSNI method](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) to create the items/entries of your Array/Map as follows:

```
 JsArray arr = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
 arr.push(newEntry("Mr.", "Bill", "Gates"));      

 ....

 private final native JavaScriptObject newEntry(String title, 
                               String firstname, String lastname)/*-{
     return {title: title, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname};
 }-*/;
```

You could also try to create the data structure you have in mind using the JSON utility methods: Put [JSONObjects](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html) inside a [JSONArray](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONArray.html).

Comment: This is what i did almost, but instead just having a JSNI Method, I extended the JavaScriptObject class and created my own datastructure class and added the object of that to the JsArray `JsArray<personJs> persons = JavascriptObject.createArray().cast(); persons.push((personJs)JavaScriptObject.createObject().set(fname,age,...));`

Comment: that should work, too! Probably longer in terms of LOC but your approach should be more robust for refactoring etc. since it is 'more Java'. Why did you name your JSO `personJs` and not `PersonJs`?

Comment: well actually its a typing mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$wnd.v` will contain an array of objects.
Note: you will need to find a way how to convert your Java objects to a JSON (i used [restygwt](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html)).

```
class PersonList {
    List<Person> list;
}

class Person {
    String title;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Person () {}

    public Person(String title, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.title = title;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}


public class Main implements EntryPoint {

    public interface PersonCodec extends JsonEncoderDecoder<PersonList> {
    }

    PersonCodec personCodec = GWT.create(PersonCodec.class);

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

        list.add(new Person("Mr.", "Bill", "Gates"));
        list.add(new Person("Mr.", "Andrey", "Mormysh"));

        PersonList personList = new PersonList();
        personList.list = list;

        String json = personCodec.encode(personList).toString();

        setPersonList(json);
    }


    public static native void setPersonList(String personListJson)/*-{
        $wnd.v = eval("(" + personListJson + ")").list;
        alert($wnd.v[0].firstName); // Output: 'Bill'
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: I found extending the javascriptObject class directly and adding it to a JsArray as mentioned in the below answer seems more easier

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty `JavaScriptObject` from Java but you cannot populate them from there, so use the dark side of the force:

```
private native JavaScriptObject putString(JavaScriptObject jso, String key, String value)/*-{
    jso[key] = value;
    return jso;
}-*/;

private native JavaScriptObject putObject(JavaScriptObject jso, String key, JavaScriptObject value)/*-{
    jso[key] = value;
    return jso;
}-*/;

void someJavaFunction() {
    JavaScriptObject fromJava = JavaScriptObject.createObject();
    fromJava = putString(fromJava, "foo", "bar");
    fromJava = putObject(fromJava, "baz", fromJava);
}
```