# GWT: Parsing a JavaScript associative array using JSNI JsArrayString

Tags: arrays, gwt, jsni, associative

I am using JSNI to pass some parameters to the GWT app, so far I have managed to pass a simple String array (JsArrayString) but I would like to pass an associative array though and don't know how to extract the data with the keys (I've managed to pass the array on to the GWT app but can't parse it), like this:

```
public static native void exportFunction() /*-{
    $wnd.myFunction = 
        $entry(@com.mypackage.client.HelloWorld::helloWorld(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JsArrayString;));
}-*/;    

var associative = { "hello" : "world", "goodbye" : "world" };
window.myFunction(associative);

public static void helloWorld(JsArrayString strings) {
    // String value = strings.get("hello")
}
```

I've found [a topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169623/gwt-creating-associated-jsarray) that does the opposite of what I am trying to do, but can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing like an "associative array" in JS; what you're talking about is an *object*. `JsArrayString` represents a JS array that you expect to contain only strings. JS objects are represented as `JavaScriptObject`s in GWT, and there's no built-in easy way to dynamically access their properties.

If you know what properties you need to access, you'd better create a `JavaScriptObject` subclass, also known as [an overlay type](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html):

```java
public class MyObj extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected MyObj() { /* required by GWT */ }

  public final native String getHello() /*-{ return this.hello }-*/;
  public final native String getGoodbye() /*-{ return this.goodbye }-*/;
}

…

public static void helloWorld(MyObj strings) {
  String value = strings.getHello();
}
```

If you don't know what properties the object will have and want to discover them dynamically, then you can wrap a `JavaScriptObject` into a `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`, but it's less readable and creates spurious short-lived objects:

```java
public static void helloWorld(JavaScriptObject strings) {
  JSONObject o = new JSONObject(strings);
  // Beware: will throw if there's no "hello" property in the object
  String value = o.get("hello").isString().stringValue();
}
```

---

OK, I lied, there's an easy built-in way, but it's experimental (and possibly broken), and is designed to work only in modern browsers (i.e. not IE 9 and below, possibly not Opera 12 and below): you can use `elemental.js.util.JsMapFromStringTo` and similar classes.

Comment: exactly what I needed! I do know what properties I need to access so the first solution worked perfectly :) thanks!